# redirect from component level after specific dispatch - redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a fairly simple use case, but having a hard to find the appropriate answer. I'm using React,Redux,React Router & redux thunk middleware.

Lets say, I have two module food-tags & food. These modules have individual create,list,edit page/component. In practical use case, food-tags have no special value. Whenever a food object is created, separated tags are inserted into the food object's tags property.

General use case is that, after any item is created successfully, react router redirects it to the list page.

whenever i'm calling the createTag action from food-tag module, I can do it in a hacky way. like just after the success dispatch, i can call

`browserHistory.push('/dashboard/tags')`

this leads me to a problem where i can create food-tag inline from the food create component. Codes are given below

**actions.js**

```
export function createTag(tag) {
return function (dispatch) {
    axios.post(API_URL + 'api/tags', tag)
        .then((response) => { 
            // I CAN DO REDIRECT HERE,BUT THIS CAUSES THE PROBLEM
            dispatch({type: 'TAG_CREATE_RESOLVED', payload:response});
            toastr.success('Tag created Successfully.......!');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({type: 'TAG_CREATE_REJECTED', payload: err});
            toastr.warning(err.message);
        })
    }
}
```

**component/container.js**

```
createTag () {
  //validatation & others....
  this.props.createTag(tag)
}
```

**react-redux connection**

```
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        createTag: createTag
    }, dispatch)
}
```

Almost same pattern in food/create.js

```
$('#food-tags').select2(select2settings).on('select2:selecting', function (event) {
        let isNewTagCreated = event.params.args.data.newOption,
            name = event.params.args.data.text;
        if (isNewTagCreated && name !== '') {
            reactDOM.props.createTag({name}); // reactDOM = this context here
        }
    });
```

What I want basically that, I want to get access in the component level which action type is dispatching so that i can redirect from component & show notifications as well instead of action thunk. May be i'm not thinking in the proper way. there could be a dead simple work around.

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to move `toastr.success` call into component code, but you don't know how, right?

Comment: yes. also the redirection code, `browserHistory.push`

Answer (score 1):

It's good to know that `redux-thunk` passed out return value from the function. So you can return the promise from the action creator and wait until it will be finished in you component code

```
export function createTag(tag) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return axios.post(API_URL + 'api/tags', tag) // return value is important here
      .then((response) => dispatch({type: 'TAG_CREATE_RESOLVED', payload:response}))
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: 'TAG_CREATE_REJECTED', payload: err})
        throw err; // you need to throw again to make it possible add more error handlers in component
      })
  }
}
```

Then in your component code

```
createTag () {
  this.props.createTag(tag)
    .then(() => {
      toastr.success('Tag created Successfully.......!');
      this.props.router.push() // I assume that you have wrapped into `withRouter`
    })
    .catch(err => {
       toastr.warning(err.message);
    });

}
```

Now you have proper split up between action logic and user interface.

Comment: thanks for your answer. basically I myself came out with similar solution. Instead I passed callback. here's the gist

https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/issues/96